# Are Http Handlers the appropriate choice of architecture?

Tags: jquery, .net, web-services, architecture

Currently our software consists of a winForms app that calls a number of web services with hundreds of web methods between them.

For many reasons, we are moving to Web only architecture (jQuery Mobile, jQuery, HTML5, LawnChair). The web page will only deal with the presentation, all of the business logic will occur server side. So I need to call these web services from the web page.

I know there must be many ways to do this, for example I've been experimenting with jQuery calling server side HttpHandlers for each web method. As jQuery uses JSON, I can't call XML SOAP directly, so need a new layer to add over the top that I can call from jQuery.

However, is this the correct approach? is there another, more appropriate approach, that is less effort to implement, [possibly using WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/10/29/working-with-untyped-json-in-a-wcf-service.aspx), or something else I have overlooked?

Comment: I am not entirely sure if you are asking about the server side code or the client code.. so i answered about client requests, as it should not be necessary to modify any existing services or code for them.. unless you are creating a new bridged API or something?

Comment: @ppumkin Server side Handlers called from jQuery which uses JSON. the current web services we use are XML SOAP, these can't change for backwards compatibility, so we need something in the middle.

Comment: oh right.. bummer so my answer is rubbish. sorry. and I think what you are doing.. well unforgivable is the only way(at least that i know of)

Comment: @ppumkin sorry I don't understand... what I am doing is unforgivable? do you mean it is the only way?

Comment: This is why you don't use SOAP. Good luck talking to the SOAP API.

Comment: Sorry, I meant unfortunately (dictionary fail). Yes. You have to rewrite it but you don't necessarily need `httphandlers`

Answer (score 2):

You can consume XML Web Services from jQuery. It will work with XML messages just fine. However, creating and reading SOAP messages in JavaScript sucks.

What is appropriate depends on you. However, using WCF REST or even better [ASP.NET MVC4 WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) will bootstrap your application through the plumbing and let you concentrate on delivering a working application fairly quickly. However, this will require some rewriting of your original services (Which it seems you are destined for anyways).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help you but we use a webservice like `ajax.asmx` and we call it using jQueries ajax

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports ClsLib
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Ajax

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Function function1(byval first as string, byval second as string) as string
    'do something here
    Return someJsonAsString
End Function

End Class
```

Something like that could help you I suppose.

But you can make your own classes to handle the existing SOAP XML services it jsut requries more client side code

```
var productServiceUrl = 'http://localhost:57299/ProductService.asmx?op=SaveProduct'; // Preferably write this out from server side

function beginSaveProduct(productID, productName, manufactureDate)
{
var soapMessage =
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
<soap:Body> \
<SaveProduct xmlns="http://sh.inobido.com/"> \
<productID>' + productID + '</productID> \
<productName>' + productName + '</productName> \
<manufactureDate>' + manufactureDate + '</manufactureDate> \
</SaveProduct> \
</soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>';

$.ajax({
url: productServiceUrl,
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml",
data: soapMessage,
complete: endSaveProduct,
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});

return false;
}

function endSaveProduct(xmlHttpRequest, status)
{
 $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML)
    .find('SaveProductResult')
    .each(function()
 {
   var name = $(this).find('Name').text();
 });
}
```

And parsing SOAP responses in jQuery.. I think there are plugins for that.

Comment: Wouldn't that require modification of the existing services? If I change their interface, our existing client application will break.

Comment: Its difficult to determine what to change. It think the best long term solution is make a separate JSON friendly service/interface that calls the same business logic your SOAP alternative service does, and just use jQuery without any more complicated client side source code and phase out the soap service to avoid maintaineing  both.